# When creating a new user, the supplied UID does not come from the next available number

Tags: users, postfix

For example the most recent user on my CentOS 8 system has a UID of 1010. But when I create a new one sudo adduser user, I see the UID starts on 2001 id user. However, when creating using Webmin panel it picks 1011 correctly. Why is this like this?

What I can tell right now is when following a tutorial about setting up PostfixAdmin it says:

> ```
> virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
> virtual_minimum_uid = 2000
> virtual_uid_maps = static:2000
> virtual_gid_maps = static:2000
> ```
>
> The first line defines the base location of mail files. The remaining 3 lines define which user ID and group ID Postfix will use when delivering incoming emails to the mailbox. We use the user ID 2000 and group ID 2000.

Can this be the reason? If so how or can I tell the system to change its counter back to 1011 or higher? Or at least if you can tell me how to check if the UID is not yet taken.

Comment: That's correct. I didn't copy-paste all the lines. But it's fixed now.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show what you did on the command line where you say *"buth when I create a new one"*.

Comment: Which OS or Linux distribution is this please

Comment: This is on a CentOS 8 distribution.

Comment: 1) Have you created OS user with id 2000? (check `/etc/passwd`) 2) Is `/etc/adduser.conf` modified? (especially `FIRST_UID` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have picked the next available UID and GID and not the ones from the tutorial. And so I did these:

> ```
>     sudo usermod -u newuid vmail
>     sudo groupmod -g newgid vmail
> ```

Then

> ```
>     sudo find / -user olduid -exec chown -h vmail {} \;
>     sudo find / -group oldgid -exec chgrp -h vmail {} \;
> ```